# How to solve $y'(x)+4y'(\frac{x}{2})+1=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to find the general solution of the $$y'(x)+4y'(\frac{x}{2})+1=0$$ as follow:

1-the complementary solution
$$y'(x)+4y(\frac{x}{2})=0$$
$$y_c=e^{rx}$$
so
$$y'(x)=re^{rx}$$
$$y'(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{r}{2}e^{\frac{rx}{2}}$$
then 
$$re^{rx}+2re^{\frac{rx}{2}}=0$$
$$re^{\frac{rx}{2}}(e^{\frac{rx}{2}}+2)=0$$
and what after that ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that taking the derivative of
$$
y(x)+8y(\frac{x}{2}) + x + C = 0
$$ lead to your equation.

Try $y(x) = ax + b$ then
$$
(ax + b) + 8(a\frac{x}{2} + b) + x + C = 0
$$ which is the same as
$$
 (5a + 1)x + (9b + C) = 0
$$
Now this lead to
$$
5a + 1 = 0
$$ and $a = -1/5$ and likewise $b = - C/9$ now $C$ is arbritrary and hence we can write a solution as
$$
y(x) = D - \frac{x}{5},
$$ with arbrirary constant $D$